# I want to bind the three different dropdownlist values in to single column in database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to bind the three different dropdownlist values into single column in database.

```
protected void BookNow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Session["Date"]=ddlDate.SelectedItem+ ddlMonth.SelectedItem+ddlYear.SelectedItem;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            string date = ddlYear.SelectedValue.ToString() + "/" + ddlMonth.SelectedValue.ToString() + "/" + ddlDate.SelectedValue.ToString();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"insert into OnlineBookingEvent(BookingEvent,BookeventDate,cdt,udt)values 
                             (@BookingEvent,@BookeventDate,@cdt,@udt)", conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookingEvent", ddlEventName.SelectedItem);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookeventDate",date);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cdt", System.DateTime.Now);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@udt", System.DateTime.Now);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

Comment: Elaborate what you want to do..Your question and code makes no sense..

Comment: Nothing to do with binding in your question.

Comment: IF you want to place the values of three dropdownlist into a single cell in database,then append these three values to a string and pass that string as parameter to your sql..

Comment: Except it's a date, well may be....

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to pass **"@BookeventDate"** parameter in data format, please try following code:

```
 protected void BookNow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Session["Date"]=ddlDate.SelectedItem+ ddlMonth.SelectedItem+ddlYear.SelectedItem;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();

            //string date = ddlYear.SelectedValue.ToString() + "/" + ddlMonth.SelectedValue.ToString() + "/" + ddlDate.SelectedValue.ToString();
            int year = Convert.ToInt32(ddlYear.SelectedValue.ToString());
            int month = Convert.ToInt32(ddlMonth.SelectedValue.ToString());
            int day = Convert.ToInt32(ddlDate.SelectedValue.ToString());
            DateTime date = new DateTime(year, month, day);

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"insert into OnlineBookingEvent(BookingEvent,BookeventDate,cdt,udt)values 
                             (@BookingEvent,@BookeventDate,@cdt,@udt)", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookingEvent", ddlEventName.SelectedItem);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookeventDate", date);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cdt", System.DateTime.Now);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@udt", System.DateTime.Now);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should convert the date parameter in datetime format
string date = Convert.toDateTime(ddlYear.SelectedValue.ToString() + "/" + ddlMonth.SelectedValue.ToString() + "/" + ddlDate.SelectedValue.ToString());
or
string date = DateTime.parse(ddlYear.SelectedValue.ToString() + "/" + ddlMonth.SelectedValue.ToString() + "/" + ddlDate.SelectedValue.ToString());